# Restore Hyper-V from "Windows Server Backup" Tool

Tags: restore, hyper-v

There

I want to restore an exist Hyper-V VM as another new VM from "Windows Server Backup" image, I restored all files of exist Hyper-V to another folder (on the same host machine,see screenshot).
And then I create a new VM by Hyper-V wizard, just attaching restored VHD file for the new VM. The new VM running smoothly, but the files in the new VM are not my expectation. The new machine looks like the initial state of the exist VM in several years before.But I restored from yesterday's backup.
There are also other restored file (see screenshot ), but it seems does not used for the new VM.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find the a solution from internet. I need to manually merge all the AVHD files into their parents individually. At last, there will only be one VHD file. Attach it for the new VM, and I get the last status of original machine on the restored new machine.

Details, see here:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/6257.manually-merge-avhd-to-vhd-in-hyper-v.aspx

additional comments: when I start the restored machine, the windows OS of VM prompt to hard disk checking, if you see this, probably some of VM files broken, for me: one of TFS db is suspend. So I recover the VM from backup again, and merge the AVHD files to parents individually again.